# "Unsupported Media Type" error 415 (octet-stream)

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-headers

Desenvolvi uma controller que gera um arquivo excel com um gráfico, mas quando altero o atributo "produces" do mapeamento, sempre recebo o erro conforme mencionado no título.
Request headers:
[image]

Esse é o código da controller a qual tenho que gerar o arquivo e fazer o download direto pelo browser:

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/exportfile/excel", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> exportExcel(@RequestBody ClientDataObjectRequest clientDataObjectRequest) {

        ByteArrayInputStream file = generateCSVExcelService.generateFileDetailsWithChart(clientDataObjectRequest);

        String dateFile = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(new java.util.Date());
        String timeFile = new SimpleDateFormat("HH-mm").format(new java.util.Date());
        String fileName = clientDataObjectRequest.getMetricName().replace(" ","_") + "_" + dateFile + "T" + timeFile;

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", fileName + ".xlsx");
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        //headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".xlsx");
        //headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new InputStreamResource(file), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Como você pode ver, estou usando os "produces" como "APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE", bem como os headers do request e da response.
O que está faltando aqui?

Para gerar o arquivo, estou recebendo um request body no formato json com os dados:

```
{
    "metricName":"Turnover Rate",
    "dataFormatCodeValue": "currency",
    "clientDataRequest":[
       {
          "clientName":"client 1",
          "value":"1"
       },
       {
          "clientName":"client 2",
          "value":"2"
       },
       {
          "clientName":"client 3",
          "value":"53.78"
       },
       {
          "clientName":"client 4",
          "value":"3"
       },
       {
          "clientName":"client 5555555",
          "value":"4"
       },
       {
          "clientName":"client 6",
          "value":"33"
       },
       {
          "clientName":"client 7",
          "value":"0"
       },
       {
          "clientName":"client 8",
          "value":"8.5"
       }
    ]
}
```

Comment: O que acontece se no `Content-Type` do request você colocar `application/json`?

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza deu certo colocando ```application/json```. Porém, como eu garanto que, quando o front fizer chamada para esse método, o download do arquivo será iniciado?

Comment: Descomenta a linha `headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".xlsx");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde,

Pelo que entendi, você está recebendo um Json e retornando um Octet, não seria isso:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/exportfile/excel", 
produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE, 
consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```